# Java Spring - How to take in RequestParam, and remove from url?

Tags: java, spring, url, http-request-parameters

Sometimes I will want to pass in an identifier to my website through the url, but I don't want to display this to the user. Is there a simple way to take in a request param but not display it to the user when loading the page?

This is a general idea of how my code is set up currently

```
@GetMapping("/somePage")
public ModelAndView get(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                        @RequestParam(value = "someId", required = false) String someId) {
```

I know I could theoretically do this on the javascript side, but that seems to require the page to reload or mess with the history.

Comment: Either redirect user to another url without this parameter (you could store the parameter value in request attributes for example) or do this with javascript history api. Overall sounds like a bad idea. What if your user hits F5 - they would get another response.

Comment: You could put the "hidden" value in a custom header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is bad practice - if it's passed in the URL, it'll be visible in the user's browser history. POST is probably the best practice here.

But to answer your actual question:

Put your custom value into a header and redirect?

Something along these lines (untested)

```java
headers.set("X-Custom-Header1", someId);
headers.set("Location", "/newEndpoint");
return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

Comment: This works well for my use case. Why is it bad practice exactly? Just curious

Comment: @JR3652 passing stuff in the URL is almost always going to be visible with minimum effort - even with a workaround like this isn't not suitable for sensitive data.